# LibGdx Polygon.getTransformedVerticies() not returning the array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, libgdx, polygon

I have quite a simple problem that just makes no sense to me.

I have a method drawStar() in my Helper class:

```
public void drawStar(Star star) {

     shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
     shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
     poly[star.id].setVertices(star.verticesStar);
     if(star.rotation > 0){
         poly[star.id].rotate(star.rotation);
         poly[star.id].setOrigin(star.originX, star.originY);
         shapeRenderer.polygon(poly[star.id].getTransformedVertices()); 
     }else if(star.rotation == 0){
         shapeRenderer.polygon(star.verticiesStar);
     }
     shapeRenderer.end();
     System.out.println(poly[1].getTransformedVertices()[5]); //WORKS FINE
}
```

The above simply takes the dimensions and vertices of a star object I pass it and draws it accurately with an array of polygons. There are no problems at this stage.

The problem is when I try to access the POLYGON ARRAY in another class, I do this for example:

```
Polygon[] poly = new Polygon[50];
poly = Helper.poly;
System.out.println(poly[1].getTransformedVertices()[5]); //SAYS ARRAY INDEXOUTOFBOUNDS
```

I can print out poly[1].getTransformedVertices().length , which will accurately return 20 which is the size of the vertices array of my star and this is the same answer both in the Helper class and the other class, however when I attempt to print out any one of these vertices individually in the other class it will say array indexoutofbounds.

**ADDITIONAL DEBUGGING**
In the other class, this works:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < Helper.poly[1].getTransformedVertices().length; i++){
        System.out.println(Helper.poly[1].getTransformedVertices()[1]); //0-19 works fine as an index
    }
```

But this fails:

```
    System.out.println(Helper.poly[1].getTransformedVertices()[1]); //0-19 always returns indexoutofbounds
```

Why does a for loop accurately return the transformed vertices, but the exact same variable outside the for loop fails and says array index out of bounds? If Helper.poly[1].getTransformedVertices().length returns 20, indicated the array size is 20, why does Helper.poly[1].getTransformedVertices()[1] fail? and only works inside a for loop?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the polygon.getTransformedVerticies() initially in the update method would be array size of 0 and then populate itself, so the for loop would work only when the array was populated but brute forcing an index wouldnt work. I added this line and it worked fine.

```
    if(poly.getTransformedVertices().length != 0){
        System.out.println(poly.getTransformedVertices()[0]);
    }
```